# Request for somebody to comment on a section of a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-drive

How can I request for one of the people with access to a Google Docs document to comment on a specific section of it? Can a section be tagged as "request for comments" towards a specific user of that document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert -> Comment. Then put `+` followed by the user's e-mail address. For example, `+username@example.com Please revise this section.`

Comment: Damn... That's pretty spiffy.