# Can I get a permalink for a comment in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, collaboration

I will probably just go ahead and tag people in my comment ([Request for somebody to comment on a section of a Google Docs document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/request-for-somebody-to-comment-on-a-section-of-a-google-docs-document)) for now, but I was hoping there would be a better way to do this.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get a link that takes people directly to my comment on a large Google Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I didn't notice this before, or Google just added it: you can get the hyperlink for a comment in the "Comments" menu on the right of the toolbar beside the chat button.

[image: How to get the comment link]